# Dynamic Arrays in solidity Structs

Tags: solidity, struct, constructor

I have question about creating Struct where size of array passed to that struct could have different lengths. As in code below I could pass to this Recipe 2 ingredients, 3 ingredients or whatever amount if ingredients I would like with corresponding array of amounts.

Unfortunately I'm getting error:

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from uint8[2] memory to uint256[] memory requested.
```

I know that this comes from that I am passing fixed array size to dynamic array pole in Struct, what could be solution for that, if I want to be able to pass different sizes of arrays?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Game {
    address public owner;

    // RECIPES
    mapping(uint256 => Recipe) private recipeInfo;

    struct Recipe {
        uint256 recipeId;
        uint256[] ingredientId;
        uint256[] ingredientAmount;
        uint256 ethCost;
    }

    // constructor of game;
    function Game() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        recipeInfo[1] = Recipe(1, [1, 5], [100, 100], 50000000);
        recipeInfo[2] = Recipe(2, [2, 3, 4], [100, 200, 300], 100000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: have tried the explicit conversion ? `uint256[]([1,5])`

Comment: Yes I have tried: but

`Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256[2] memory" to "uint256[] memory"`

Answer (score 6):

From https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#array-literals-inline-arrays:

> Note that currently, fixed size memory arrays cannot be assigned to dynamically-sized memory arrays, i.e. the following is not possible:
>
> ```
> // This will not compile.
>
> pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
>
> contract C {
>     function f() public {
>         // The next line creates a type error because uint[3] memory
>         // cannot be converted to uint[] memory.
>         uint[] x = [uint(1), 3, 4];
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> It is planned to remove this restriction in the future but currently creates some complications because of how arrays are passed in the ABI.

For now, I suppose you'd have to do something like this:

```
uint256[] memory foo = new uint256[](2);
foo[0] = 1;
foo[1] = 5;
recipeInfo[1] = Recipe(1, foo, ...);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. It worked. I was aware of that, fom solidity and couldn't get around it.

Is this approach efficient in terms of gas cost?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.